# How to make a Python program that will reads references from one file and searches for their matching record in another file

Tags: python

I need help to write a program that reads references from one file and searches for their matching record in another file.

If it matches the record it is to print the reference and the title.
If it doesn’t match the record it is to write the reference and “Not Found”.

File 1:

```
B21212
F12321
C12345
A09876
Q21212
D23234
A12345
```

File 2:

```
A12345,Noddy in Toy Town
B21212,The Famous Five
E98767,Lord of The Rings
C12345,Casino Royale
A09876,Staff Handbook
D23234,Pinky and Perky
```

So it will need to find the book id from first file and search for it in file 2.

[image: The image is the 2 files]

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Can you show it to us?

Comment: What part do you have problems with? Reading the files? Finding the 'references' in the other file? Writing a new file? Include what you have tried and be more specific about what the problem here is.

Comment: @JennySmith well obviously you start with reading up on how to read a file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest put the content of `file2` into a dict (very simple, just use [`str.split(',')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)), and use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method to search it like below:

```
with open('file2') as f:
    d = dict(i.strip().split(',') for i in f)
with open('file1') as f:
    l = f.read().splitlines()

for i in l:
    print(i, d.get(i, '<Not Found>'))
```

Demo:

```
B21212 The Famous Five
F12321 <Not Found>
C12345 Casino Royale
A09876 Staff Handbook
Q21212 <Not Found>
D23234 Pinky and Perky
A12345 Noddy in Toy Town
```

Answer (score 1):

This just Another option that similiar with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34572244/3445802

```
with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('file1.txt', 'r') as ini:
        _dict = dict(p.strip().split(',') for p in f)
        _list = ini.read().splitlines()

        for key in _list:
            if key not in _dict.keys():
                print key, ' <is not found>'
            else:
                print key, _dict.get(key)
```

And then result of it:

```
B21212 The Famous Five                                                                                                                                       
F12321  <is not found>                                                                                                                                       
C12345 Casino Royale                                                                                                                                         
A09876 Staff Handbook                                                                                                                                        
Q21212  <is not found>                                                                                                                                       
D23234 Pinky and Perky                                                                                                                                       
A12345 Noddy in Toy Town
```